# Task in daily products generated not in duration

Tags: task, product, ms-project

I have a project which contains a task for creation 1000 products in 10 days (daily 100 products).

I have distributed that in 10 employees mean every employee have to create daily 10 products not matter how many hours he spent. I am unable to find how to create that task and monitor accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use MS-Project to model this kind of task scheduling behaviour since its resource loading and task scheduling is based on knowing how much work (expressed as time) is needed to complete a task.

You can force MS-Project to have a 10-day duration, irrespective of the resources applied, by setting Work=10d and making the task Fixed Duration (both before adding any resources), but that cannot be used to divide up piece-work amongst resources assigned to that task.